# C#: string like "bool" or "double" to actual type?

Tags: c#, reflection, types

The title may have said enough but I'll explain it anyway:

My application gets a string like "bool" or "double" from a random data source. What I want using that string is to create an actual object with the type specified in that string.

So a string like "int" will give me a new object of type int.

Is this even possible? I've seen some examples that use a switch-case structure, but I'd rather see a function that is already implemented.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "to create an actual object with the type specified in that string." --- and what to do with it? "I've seen some examples that use a switch-case structure, but I'd rather see a function that is already implemented." --- implement it (it's really easy) and it will be already implemented, by you.

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: As the strings you are getting are not the full-qualified CLI names of the types (e.g. `int` instead of `System.Int32`), but another notation (inspired by C# keywords), I think there is no such pre-defined function. Instead of a switch-case mapping, would a `Dictionary<string, Type>` do? That seems more flexible (customizeable at runtime) to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can form the string to the fully qualified type, you can do this kind of thing...

```
object num = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("System.Int32"));
```

Comment: ... combined with @ColinE's answer I'll go with this! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Activator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.aspx) class to create objects of a given type. It has many methods, some of which use string to describe the type. Although, note that `int` is not a fully qualified type, you would need to use `System.Int32`

Comment: Okay, I can live with that. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

`Activator.CreateInstance` should be able to do the trick..

```
bool myVar = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("System.Boolean"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Can use [Activator.CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/wccyzw83.aspx)  method where like a parameter use a `Type`, recovered by, for example, `typeof(double)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use **dynamic** keyword

```
string input = "int"
dynamic x = string.Empty;

switch(input)
{
case 'int':
x =34;
break;
case 'string':
x ="234";
break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly possible with Reflection. **[Activator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.aspx)** class creates instances of a specified type. There are `CreateInstance` method overloads which use string type name.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible - the simplest implementation being:

```
//case insensitive lookup and don't throw exception
Type t = Type.GetType(name, false, true);

if(t != null)
  return Activator.CreateInstance(t);
```

[Here's the MSDN topic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a87che9d.aspx) for the `Type.GetType` overload I'm using there.

However you will fast see that this has many shortfalls - not least that the `name` will have to be the assembly qualified type name of the type in question (unless it's in mscorlib. in which case just the namespace-qualified name will do).  And also a default constructor is required (note - one with all-optional parameters doesn't count) - but then I think that's probably reasonable.

Also - generics will be horrific with this; but possible.

So your next step will be to have a mapping dictionary of `string` to `Type` which you consult first to see if you have a shortcut defined:

```
private Dictionary<string, Type> _knownTypes = 
  new Dictionary<string, Type>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

private Type GetShortcutType(string name)
{
  Type toReturn = null;
  _knownTypes.TryGetValue(name, out toReturn);
  return toReturn; //returns null if not found
}
```

And now you can change the type lookup line in the first code example to:

```
Type t = GetShortcutType(name) ?? Type.GetType(name, false, true);
```

Now you just have a setup method to setup your aliases - which can do this:

```
_knownTypes["int"] = typeof(int);
_knownTypes["double"] = typeof(double);
```

Note that the case-insensitivity of the type lookups here may or may not be desirable - it depends on how easy/flexible you want your system to be.